# Importing jQuery bootstrap-table plugin in Vue in a bad way

Tags: jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-table

I'm new using VUE and I need help importing [bootstrap table](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/vuejs/introduction/) jQuery plugin.

I load jQuery globally and it works nice. Then I have a vue component having an old table (id="tableTest")

This is the component script called in "updated" hook:

```
    console.log("table: "+  $("#tableTest").length);

    $("#tableTest").bootstrapTable({
        'card-view':true
    });
```

The console log returns the table length "1" so the table exists in DOM

But then I got the warning:

> Error in updated hook: "TypeError: $(...).bootstrapTable is not a function"

I have imported the plugin using **npm** and *--save*  and then into my component imported as

> import bootstrapTable from 'bootstrap-table';

How can I fix it?

Comment: may you use [bootstrap-vue table](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table)?

Comment: thanks but I need this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm importing the plugin in a bad way:

switch from:

> import bootstrapTable from 'bootstrap-table';

to

> import  'bootstrap-table';

So it's imported and used properly